# Recover the ISPConfig 3 passwords

Tags: encryption, password-recovery

I have a backup of the old ISPConfig database. There are tons of email accounts and their aliases. I need to add them manually to the newer version of ISPConfig (this database is not compatible with the new version). I read that ISPConfig uses the "crypt" encryption type with salt. Is there any way to crack these hashes? I just need a tool which will allow me to brute force them. There are many ways to crack md5 hash so I guess that the "crypt" hashes won't be a problem right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they were just encrypted then you could use a rainbow table to match the results. Rainbow tables are a dictionary of encrypted passwords, so you just match the encrypted result and look up the password.  If they are salted then it is secured against this hack and you are probably not going to crack it.